# Why is react-admin ignoring my proxy configuration?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-admin, http-proxy-middleware

I am in the middle of upgrading my project from react-admin v3 to v4.  I am currently stuck because the proxy configuration line in my package.json file is not working. It was working fine in v3.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:80",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.10.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "gojs": "^2.2.16",
    "gojs-react": "^1.1.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "ra-compact-ui": "^1.1.5",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-admin": "^4.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my `setupProxy.js` file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:80',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

I have also tried using `http-proxy-middleware` as described in this article:
https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

My app starts and runs fine, but all of the backend calls are being made to the same port that the app is running on (3006).

I have deleted the `node_modules` folder and the `yarn.lock` file, then re-ran `yarn install` and finally `yarn start` but nothing I do seems to make any difference.

Comment: can you share you setupproxy.js file?

Comment: Your problem isn't with react-admin, but with create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was only in my head.

I have not finished rewriting my dataProvider, so all of the ajax calls were failing.  I saw the port 3006 on the calls and *assumed* the problem was due to the proxy.  After I cleared my head, I realized that's not how proxies work.  They do not *rewrite* the port in the URL.  The proxy *intercepts* the call on the development server and proxies it over to port 80.  That means the developer console in my browser will always show port 3006.

Anyway, once I get my dataProvider straightened out everything should be ok.